# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelot'

Tags: python, pip, python-camelot

I want to extract tables from pdf and for that
I used Camelot. But I'm getting this error whenever I try to import it:

```
    import camelot
    Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<ipython-input-11-679d8f55abf0>", line 1, in <module>
    import camelot

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelot'
```

I've tried installing camelot using:

```
   pip install camelot-py[cv]
```

and

```
   pip install camelot-py[all]
```

but I'm getting the same error again and again. How do I remove this?
Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is camelot installed for the version of python you're running your script with? Make sure you have camelot for python3.7 if you are using it in a python3.7 script, etc.

Comment: i'm using python 3.7 and camelot-py 0.7.3

Answer (score 3):

Check for your python version by writing python --version in the command prompt with the path where python is installed.

For python 3.7, try:

```
pip install camelot-py
```

https://pypi.org/project/camelot-py/

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Do you get any errors while installing the Camelot package? There are so many dependencies involved.

Comment: [link](https://readthedocs.org/projects/camelot-py/downloads/pdf/master/)
Did you follow the steps mentioned here?

Answer (score 2):

If using conda (this is what I'd recommend):
`conda install -c conda-forge camelot-py`

If using pip (may have to manually handle dependencies): `pip install camelot-py[cv]`

Official installation instructions: https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install.html#install

Answer (score 1):

In your python environment you have to install [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library.

You can install Camelot python with following command:

`pip install Camelot`

After the installation of Camelot python library, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Camelot' error will be solved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Camelot in correct python version directory using
''''python2.7 -m pip install''''
Use your python version number instead of 2.7 above